# Dúvida na Geração de boleto bancário Bradesco via PHP

Tags: php, boleto

Estou com dúvidas quanto a geração de Boleto bancário Bradesco via PHP.
Estou utilizando os códigos do projeto boletophp.
Minha dúvida é mais conceitual do que técnica.

O campo Nº do documento, é um campo para controle interno dos boletos gerados, ou tenho que seguir alguma regra?

O que é o campo Nosso número? Esse campo muda a cada boleto gerado, ou é um número fixo como agência e conta?

É a primeira vez que estou trabalhando com geração de boletos.

Comment: Na verdade a dúvida não é nem conceitual, é administrativa. Peça o manual para o Bradesco. Talvez seja possível baixar pela internet mas não tenho nada atualizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O campo "Nosso Número" serve principalmente para seu controle interno. Você pode usar aí um número que seja incrementado a cada boleto gerado ou o ID de um pedido no seu sistema, por exemplo.

Esse número aparece na fatura do banco e é através dele que você identifica qual boleto foi pago.

Nesse caso do boleto do Bradesco no *boletophp*, o campo "Número do documento" tem o mesmo valor do "Nosso número".

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento André =)